# Question about gcc and which 32-bit x86 architecture it outputs (i386 vs i686)

Tags: c, gcc, x86, cpu-architecture, mingw-w64

Does `gcc -m32` produce a i386 or i686 executable? 

When doing `file a.out` using `gcc -m32` it will say that it is a `ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386` (I'm assuming this means i386). When I cross compile, I use `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc` which has i686 in it's name, but it also says `PE32 executable (console) Intel 80386, for MS Windows` (again, I'm assuming this means i386). 

This is a bit confusing for me because I do not know if I am wrong about `Intel 80386` meaning i386, or if `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc` is simply outputting a i386 executable instead of i686, or if i386 and i686 are the same thing.

Comment: What if you add `-march i686` as a compiler flag?  EDIT: Yeah, it looks like `-m32` does i386, but there are a whole bunch of options to control that: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html

Comment: @DanielH it said `unrecognized command line option '-march’` so i replaced it with `-march=i686` and it still says `Intel 80386`

Comment: I believe these are pretty much the same. Intel 386 is a very old processor. 686 is the sixth generation of x86 which is pretty, which is just a newer one in the line of 32-bit family

Comment: @EugeneSh. Ah thanks, I was asking because when I was packaging one of my programs, I was naming it `clibasic-{windows/linux}-amd64.zip` and `clibasic-{windows/linux}-i386` and i was wondering if I should change it to `i686`

Comment: The only potential difference is whether the resulting program would run on CPUs *older* than the 686 (aka Pentium Pro), which was released in 1995.  So if you don't care about supporting very old machines, it likely doesn't matter.

Comment: I’m not at all confident, but I *think* the `file` utility can’t tell the difference.  Skimming Wikipedia on the ELF format, it looks like there’s a byte that says 32-bit vs 64-bit, and another that says x86, but nothing to distinguish in more detail.